# Using Expressions to read the code

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to read the contents of the c# code written inside a class file by writing another c# code. For example,

```
public static int GetValue()
{
    int tempValue = 10;
    return tempValue * 5;
}
```

is the code present in my class. I can get the available classes and the methods under those classes using Reflection. But I am not able to get the expression to find the logic inside the method. Is there any way to do it?

thanks
Vignesh

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: I am trying to read the code within a method and see what computations are done on which variables. So I want to check what logic is being used in the method